# How do I set the end date different from the start date?

Tags: angular, date

I have created a calendar in which I need to display the total hours worked on each day for a user.
Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Wherever the H is displayed, that is where the hours will be displayed.

I have created a method called getTimeEntrysForDateRange in which its parameters are: resourceID (it tells me which user is currently logged in), startDay, startMonth, startYear, lastDay, lastMonth, lastYear.

I was able to get the first 4 arguments correct in that for example if I am on this current month of September, the startDay, startMonth and startYear is 8/30/2020. The reason I start on that date will be apparent in the code and is obvious on the calendar (the beginning of the week starts on a Sunday), so I made a method called setDates() that will get the previous Sunday to the beginning of the month.

When I inspect the call in the networks tab, it shows both the start dates and end dates as 8/30/2020. I want to get the start date to be the firstSunday as shown on calendar and then i want the end date to be (in this case) the last Saturday of the 3rd of October.

Note: I am only displaying 35 days per month or 5 weeks.

My ts code

```js
export class CalendarHoursComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  faAngleDoubleLeft = faAngleDoubleLeft;
  faAngleDoubleRight = faAngleDoubleRight;
  allDates = [];
  allMonths = [];
  resources: IResource[] = [];
  currentDate: Date = new Date();
  hours: ITimeEntry = null;
  firstSunday: Date;
  month = [
    "January",
    "Febuary",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
  ];

  constructor(
    private server: ServerService,
    private globals: GlobalsService,
    private modalService: NgbModal
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setDates();
    this.load();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    try {
      this.modalService.dismissAll();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  load() {
    let lastSaturday = this.firstSunday;
    lastSaturday.setDate(lastSaturday.getDate() + 31);
    debugger;
    this.server.getTimeEntrysForDateRange(
      this.globals.currentUser.id,
      this.firstSunday.getMonth(),
      this.firstSunday.getDate(),
      this.firstSunday.getFullYear(),
      lastSaturday.getMonth(),
      lastSaturday.getDate(),
      lastSaturday.getFullYear(),
      (r) => this.load2(r)
    );
  }

  private load2(d: any[]) {}

  showTimeEntries(d: Date) {
    CalendarTimeEntriesComponent.show(
      this.modalService,
      this.globals.currentUser.id,
      d
    )
      .then((r) => {})
      .catch((r) => {});
  }

  setDates() {
    this.firstSunday = this.currentDate;
    while (this.firstSunday.getDate() != 1) {
      this.firstSunday = new Date(
        this.firstSunday.getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
      );
    }
    while (this.firstSunday.getDay() != 0) {
      this.firstSunday = new Date(
        this.firstSunday.getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
      );
    }
    let temp = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
      let day = new Date(this.firstSunday.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * i);
      temp.push(day);
      if (temp.length % 7 == 0) {
        this.allDates.push(temp);
        temp = [];
      }
    }
    console.log(this.allDates);
  }

  addMonths(date: Date, months: number) {
    let d = date.getDate();
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + months);
    if (date.getDate() != d) {
      date.setDate(0);
    }
    return date;
  }

  currMonth() {
    return this.month[this.currentDate.getMonth()];
  }

  nextMonth() {
    this.currentDate = this.addMonths(this.currentDate, 1);
    this.allDates = [];
    this.setDates();
  }

  previousMonth() {
    this.currentDate = this.addMonths(this.currentDate, -1);
    this.allDates = [];
    this.setDates();
  }
}
```

I don't think this is relevant but to be comprehensive here is the html code

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <table
      class="table table-bordered table-fixed-header table-striped table-narrow"
    >
      <tr class="weekdays">
        <td>Sunday</td>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>Tuesday</td>
        <td>Wednesday</td>
        <td>Thursday</td>
        <td>Friday</td>
        <td>Saturday</td>
      </tr>

      <tr *ngFor="let w of allDates">
        <td class="days" (click)="showTimeEntries(d)" *ngFor="let d of w">
          <span class="top-left">{{d.getDate()}}</span>
          <h3>H</h3>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Javascript `Date`s are mutable objects. In your `load()` code, the first few lines are the problem:

```
  load() {
    let lastSaturday = this.firstSunday;
    lastSaturday.setDate(lastSaturday.getDate() + 31);
    // ...
  }
```

That sets the local variable `lastSaturday` to point to the same `Date` object in memory as `this.firstSunday`. So on the next line, when you call `.setDate()` on it, it modifies the same object that both references are pointing to.

Instead, what you want is to copy the value of `this.firstSunday`, but get a brand new `Date` object. One way to do that is to pass the numeric value of the other date object to the `Date` constructor.

The following are equivalent:

```
const lastSaturday = new Date(+this.firstSunday);
lastSaturday.setDate(lastSaturday.getDate() + 31);

const lastSaturday = new Date(this.firstSunday.valueOf());
lastSaturday.setDate(lastSaturday.getDate() + 31);
```

Comment: I am still getting 8/30/2020 for the 2nd - 7th parameter for my getTimeEntrysForDateRange method. 8/30/20 is okay for the 2nd - 4th parameters since those are my start dates, but for the 5th - 7th parameters i want them to display or get 31 days from 8/30/2020 or 9/30/2020.